# Filter View to Specific Set of Keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I'm animating multiple characters and would like to filter my timeline keyframe view to just the relevant keyframes for my characters, instead of the entire dump of all of the keyframes for all characters and objects.

Please do not suggest the "Only View Keyframes from Selected Channels" option. This feature is completely counterproductive. Once I select all the 30-40 bones I want to see, what then? As soon as I click a bone in the viewport to move or rotate it, the entire selection destroyed, back to viewing just a single keyframe lane. I honestly don't understand why this feature exists.

I'm a bit exasperated to find no mention of this anywhere. Are there any add-ons out there that let you filter the shown keyframes to arbitrary, definable sets? Kind of like bone-selection sets, but for creating filtered timeline keyframe display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

if you turn off only show selected and then get all the objects/rigs you want showing keyframes and put them into a new collection, then use the dope sheet's filter option, go up to the filtering collection box and select the collection you just created, it should show keyframes only for the objects you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: At least it's something! Though this would mess up my scene's collection organization, at least until Blender allows stuff to be in multiple collections. But thank you regardless, I'll give it a go.